# How to increase the font size of plist editor (not code editor) in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, plist

Are there any settings in Xcode which can increase the font size of the plist editor (especially the key and the value text)?

I tried Preference → Fonts and Colors but to no avail.

[image: screenshot of plist editor]

Answer (score 2):

I too have the same requirement and couldn't find any possible way to adjust font size of plist editor in Xcode.

I ended searching for a 3rd party plist editor and came across [PlistEdit Pro](https://www.fatcatsoftware.com/plisteditpro/). It lets you choose a custom font face and font size for displaying contents of plist via preferences.

[image]